# Polar $C^*$ of the given cone

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Derive an explicit form of the polar $C^*$ of the following cone:

$C=\{(x_1,x_2): 0\le x_2\le 2x_1\}$

This is what I've done:

As $C\neq\varnothing, C^*=\{p:p^tx\le 0,\forall x\in C\}$

In this case, $C^*=\{p:p^t(x_1,x_2)\le 0,\forall (x_1,x_2)\in C\}$

To have the equality I think I should write the condition $x_1,x_2\le 0$ but if I do it, then I might be modifiying the $\forall (x_1,x_2)\in C.$

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Draw a picture and guess what the polar would be? One you do that it is straightforward to verify.

Comment: @copper.hat I drew the cone (it's a triangle on the first quadrant ) and I suppose $C^*$ should be the same triangle but on the 4th quadrant (symmetric). Am I correct?

Comment: No. Draw all points polar to the the cones generated by $(1,2)$ and $(1,0)$ and take the intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

Note that for two cones $C_1,C_2$ we have
$(C_1 + C_2)^* = C_1^* \cap C_2^*$.

Take $C_1 = \{ \lambda (1,2) \}_{\lambda \ge 0}$ and $C_2 = \{ \lambda (1,0) \}_{\lambda \ge 0}$.

Note that $C_1^* = \{ x | x_1+ 2 x_2 \le 0 \}$, $C_2^* = \{ x | x_1 \le 0 \}$ (both are hyperplanes).

**Addendum**:

Suppose $R = \{ \lambda p \}_{\lambda \ge 0 }$. Then
$R^* = \{ x | \langle x, p \rangle \le 0 \}$.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, if $p=(p_1,p_2)$ then
$R^* = \{ x | x_1 p_1 + x_2 p_2 \le 0 \}$.

Comment: where is the $p^t$ in $\{ x | x_1+ 2 x_2 \le 0 \}?$ How did you compute $\{ x | x_1+ 2 x_2 \le 0 \}?$

Comment: What vectors make an angle of $\ge 90^\circ$ with $(1,2)$? You should look at the geometry here.

Comment: The ones that are on the $ll,lll,lV$ quadrant?

Comment: You are losing me. Get a piece of paper and draw the ray from 0 that passes through $(1,2)$. Now find all points whose inner product with $(1,2)$  is negative. That is all points whose angle with $(1,2)$ is $\ge 90^\circ$.

Comment:  Now it's clear (with the Addendum), so in conclusion $C^*=(C_1+C_2)^*=\{x|x_1\le0 \land x_1\le 2x_2\}?$

Comment: Yes, but if you draw a picture it will be clear.

Comment: no it's not correct, it should be $x_1\le -2x_2$

Comment: Good catch, I missed the missing $-$ in your formula for $C^*$.